# Volley response data is not set on Bar Chart

Tags: java, android, github, graph

I want to implement bar chart on my app's fragment, where data will come from volley response. I am using `compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.2.4'` library for graph. The data is coming on response and split it successfully but when I put that data on bar chart it shows null. Please check my code and help me to solve this issue. Thank You in advance

```
public class MonthsFragment extends Fragment {

public String user_id;
// Session Manager Class
UserSessionManager session;

BarChart chartUniqueVisitors;
ArrayList<BarEntry> BARENTRY ;
ArrayList<String> BarEntryLabels ;
BarDataSet Bardataset ;
BarData BARDATA ;

public float jan, feb, mar, apr, may, jun, jul, aug, sep, oct, nov, dec;

public MonthsFragment(){}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_unique_visitors, container, false);

    session = new UserSessionManager(getContext());
    session.checkLogin();
    // get user data from session
    HashMap<String, String> user = session.getUserDetails();
    user_id = user.get(UserSessionManager.KEY_USER_ID);

    return view;
}


public void onViewCreated(View v, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(v, savedInstanceState);
    chartUniqueVisitors = (BarChart) v.findViewById(R.id.chartUniqueVisitors);

    BARENTRY = new ArrayList<>();
    BarEntryLabels = new ArrayList<String>();

    getDataForBusinessAddress();
    AddValuesToBARENTRY();
    AddValuesToBarEntryLabels();

    Bardataset = new BarDataSet(BARENTRY, "Projects");

    BARDATA = new BarData(BarEntryLabels, Bardataset);

    Bardataset.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);

    chartUniqueVisitors.setData(BARDATA);

    chartUniqueVisitors.animateY(3000);
}
```

Function to fetch the data from server

```
private void getDataForBusinessAddress() {
    String getBusinessAddressURL ="xyz.php?username="+user_id;
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,getBusinessAddressURL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            JSONArray jsonarray = null;
            try {
                jsonarray = new JSONArray(response);
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                    jan = Float.parseFloat(jsonobject.getString("Jan"));
                    feb = Float.parseFloat(jsonobject.getString("Feb"));
                    mar = Float.parseFloat(jsonobject.getString("Mar"));
                    apr = Float.parseFloat(jsonobject.getString("Apr"));
                    may = Float.parseFloat(jsonobject.getString("May"));
                    jun = Float.parseFloat(jsonobject.getString("Jun"));
                    jul = Float.parseFloat(jsonobject.getString("Jul"));
                    aug = Float.parseFloat(jsonobject.getString("Aug"));
                    sep = Float.parseFloat(jsonobject.getString("Sep"));
                    oct = Float.parseFloat(jsonobject.getString("Oct"));
                    nov = Float.parseFloat(jsonobject.getString("Nov"));
                    dec = Float.parseFloat(jsonobject.getString("Dece"));
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(),error.getMessage().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
    requestQueue.getCache().clear();
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

Function to set the data on BarEntry. I tried Log here but data is not coming

```
public void AddValuesToBARENTRY(){
    BARENTRY.add(new BarEntry(jan, 0));
    BARENTRY.add(new BarEntry(feb, 1));
    BARENTRY.add(new BarEntry(mar, 2));
    BARENTRY.add(new BarEntry(apr, 3));
    BARENTRY.add(new BarEntry(may, 4));
    BARENTRY.add(new BarEntry(jun, 5));
    BARENTRY.add(new BarEntry(jul, 6));
    BARENTRY.add(new BarEntry(aug, 7));
    BARENTRY.add(new BarEntry(sep, 8));
    BARENTRY.add(new BarEntry(oct, 9));
    BARENTRY.add(new BarEntry(nov, 10));
    BARENTRY.add(new BarEntry(dec, 11));
}
```

Function to set the name in Bar Chart

```
public void AddValuesToBarEntryLabels(){
    BarEntryLabels.add("Jan");
    BarEntryLabels.add("Feb");
    BarEntryLabels.add("Mar");
    BarEntryLabels.add("Apr");
    BarEntryLabels.add("May");
    BarEntryLabels.add("Jun");
    BarEntryLabels.add("Jul");
    BarEntryLabels.add("Aug");
    BarEntryLabels.add("Sep");
    BarEntryLabels.add("Oct");
    BarEntryLabels.add("Nov");
    BarEntryLabels.add("Dec");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please try with this code :

```
        private BarChart positiveChart;

        ArrayList<BarEntry> value;

        @Override
            public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_view_que, container, false);

                this.positiveChart = view.findViewById(R.id.positiveChart);
                value = new ArrayList<>();

    chartAdjust();  // it is optional for my required formatting
setValue();
        }


    private void chartAdjust() {
            Description description = new Description();
            description.setText("");

            positiveChart.setMaxVisibleValueCount(100);
            positiveChart.setFitBars(true);
            positiveChart.setHighlightFullBarEnabled(false);
            positiveChart.disableScroll();
            positiveChart.setDescription(description);
            positiveChart.getLegend().setEnabled(true);
            positiveChart.setDoubleTapToZoomEnabled(false);
            positiveChart.setScaleEnabled(false);
            positiveChart.getAxisLeft().setDrawLabels(false);
            positiveChart.getAxisRight().setDrawLabels(false);
            positiveChart.getXAxis().setDrawLabels(false);
            positiveChart.getAxisLeft().setDrawGridLines(false);
            positiveChart.getAxisRight().setDrawGridLines(false);
            positiveChart.getXAxis().setDrawGridLines(false);
            positiveChart.setNoDataTextColor(Color.RED);
            positiveChart.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            positiveChart.setDrawBorders(false);
            positiveChart.getXAxis().setDrawAxisLine(false);
            positiveChart.getAxisRight().setEnabled(false);
            positiveChart.getAxisLeft().setEnabled(false);
    }


public void setValue()
{
float maleOp1 = (float) (data.getAnswerOfManOption1());
            float femaleOp1 = (float) (data.getAnswerOfWomanOption1());

            xValue.add(new BarEntry(0, new float[]{maleOp1, femaleOp1}));

            BarDataSet set1;
            set1 = new BarDataSet(xValue, "");
            set1.setDrawIcons(true);
            set1.setStackLabels(new String[]{"Male", "Female"});
            set1.setDrawValues(true);
            set1.setValueTextSize(12f);
            set1.setColors(ColorTemplate.JOYFUL_COLORS);

            BarData data1 = new BarData(set1);
            data1.setBarWidth(15f);

// And BarDataSet And BarData Is set as per your required then  set  the value in the  Variable of barchart : see below you

            positiveChart.setData(data1);
            positiveChart.setFitBars(true);
            positiveChart.invalidate();
}
```

I hope this code will help you

Comment: Thank u for your reply, Let me check

Comment: Sorry I am not getting this answer, can you please explain it.

Comment: first you set the debug point and see , your response is getting successfully or not

Comment: Ya response is getting successfully on Log

Comment: So, please apply with my code, And
you get an error, when you run the app. ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174640/discussion-between-paramjeet-singh-and-talk-about-android).